# How do I include an Ember addon in an addon that I'm writing?

Tags: ember.js, add-on

I'm writing an addon and I want to use [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) as a dependency. I've installed it in the addon but, when I run my app, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'moment-from-now' could not be found
```

I've also tried importing a helper from `ember-moment`:

```
import momentFromNow from 'ember-moment/computeds/from-now';
```

and that fails with:

```
Could not find module `ember-moment/computeds/from-now`
```

FYI, I'm using `npm link` to export the addon and import it into the project.

Answer (score 0):

Place the addon (ember-moment) in the dependencies section of your addon's package.json, not the devDependencies section.